# MVC5 Dynamic route on the root

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing

I want the following to urls to be mapped dinamically to the HomeController => Index with the segment variable...

`www.site.com/one
www.site.com/two`

```
 public HomeController
    {
      [Route("{segment:string}")]//this wont work... 404
      public ActionResult Index(string segment) //one or two
      {
         return View();
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to do it like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        // other routes
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    [Route("{segment}")]
    public ActionResult test(string segment)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and accessed the following urls:

`http://localhost/TestWebApplication/segment1` -> goes to `test` action -> put `segment = "segment1"`

**So, shortly put: make sure that attribute routing is enabled and skip the string constraint (I receive an error that is not recognized).**